# Como arredondar um valor float em Firemonkey Mobile Delphi XE6?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

Estou fazendo uma aplicação mobile de pedidos para android em Delphi XE6, nesta aplicação eu faço um calculo de desconto, que divide a quantidade de Desconto dado por 100 menos o valor total, mas o valor do preço já esta vindo quebradiço da base de dados do cliente ex : 11,568.

Eu queria saber como faço para arrendondar este valor?!?!; Achei exemplos usando o 'round' mas ele arredonda de mais os valores.

Comment: Concordo com o Guilherme Bernal, caso precise de um valor maior utilize `int64` para a apresentação ao usuário final divida por 100 e utilize a função `FormatFloat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nunca nunca nunca nunca nunca nunca use um float para tratar valores monetários.**

Eles não guardam valores com precisão que se espera de dinheiro, é bem esperado que depois de alguns cálculos suma um centavo ou dois. O correto é armazenar o número total de centavos como um inteiro. Assim R$5,00 vira `500` e R$19,90 vira `1990`. Mantendo esses valores sempre como inteiros, ao longo de qualquer cálculo que faça, não precisará arredondar nem haverá problemas de precisão.

Answer (score 2):

O **Round** admite dois parâmetros. O segundo é o número de casas decimais que você deseja no resultado.

Por exemplo, se você fizer:

```
Round(11.568, 2);
```

Vai obter **11.57** (ou 11,57 quando em exibição na cultura brasileira).

O tipo ideal para trabalhar com valores monetários em Delphi, entretando, é o **Currency**.

Comment: sim o round para delphi admite dois parâmetros, mas para firemonkey mobile ele aceita apenas um !!! ; Vou tentar usar o Currency, vlw obrigado !

Comment: @Paulo Veja se o **RoundTo** está disponível. Ficaria assim: `RoundTo(11.568, -2)` (menos dois no segundo parâmetro).

Comment: O RoundTo não esta, apenas o round esta disponível para mobile, Obrigado novamente !